# merge two dataframes and create/fill non-existing rows from other one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say we have two dataframe called `df` which is the data frame that we want modification and a
`reference data` frame as the data frame should look like;

but `df` is sometimes partially missing some rows from the `reference` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame({'gr1f': ['A','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
                   'gr2p': ['CC','CC','CC','CC','CC','CC','CC'],

                   'gr3a': ['AL','AL','AL','DEL','DEL','DEL','DEL'],

                   'DP': [ 'l1yrs', 'l10yrs','l10yrs','l1yrs','l1yrs','l10yrs','l10yrs'],

                    'num_vals1' :[
                                1.138044999,
                                1.221786568,
                                1.7,
                                1.159030763,
                                1.2,
                                1.5,
                                1.238341765 ],
                    'num_vals2' :[
                                  0.166637328,
                                  0.04513741,
                                  0.12,
                                  0.141340498,
                                  0.87,
                                  0.033441602,
                                  0.01233441602]})
df
```

[image]

```
reference_df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'gr2p': ['CC','CC','CC','CC','DD','DD','DD','DD'],

                   'gr3a': ['AL','AL','AL','AL','DEL','DEL','DEL','DEL'],

                   'DP': ['l1yrs', 'l1yrs', 'l10yrs','l10yrs','l1yrs','l1yrs','l10yrs','l10yrs']})

reference_df
```

[image]

to merge this two data frame I used right join [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

```
df1 = df.merge(reference_df[['gr2p','gr3a','DP']], on = ['gr2p','gr3a','DP'], how='right').sort_values(by =['gr1f','gr2p','DP']).reset_index(drop=True)


df1
```

which yields

[image]

The expected output that I need to have

```
   gr1f gr2p    gr3a    DP     num_vals1    num_vals2   source
0   A   CC       AL    l10yrs   1.221787    0.045137    df
1   B   CC       AL    l10yrs   1.700000    0.120000    df
2   A   CC       AL    l1yrs    1.138045    0.166637    df
3   B   CC       AL    l1yrs    NaN         NaN         reference_df 
4   A   CC       DEL   l10yrs   1.50000     0.033441602 df
5   B   CC       DEL   l10yrs   1.238342    0.012334    df
6   A   CC       DEL   l1yrs    1.15903     0.1413404   df
7   B   CC       DEL   l1yrs    1.20000     0.87        df
8   A   DD       DEL   l10yrs   NaN         NaN         reference_df 
9   B   DD       DEL   l10yrs   NaN         NaN         reference_df
10  A   DD       DEL   l1yrs    NaN         NaN         reference_df
11  B   DD       DEL   l1yrs    NaN         NaN         reference_df
```

how can we achieve this final table with filling missing rows `gr1f` with `A` and `B` combinations and `DP` with 'l10yrs, l1yrs' combination. I think the expected output is showing the pattern so its a good guide.

Comment: Your expected output has some rows that are not from input, e.g. row `3`, row `4`? Also, what is the logic for the last 4 rows' `gr1f`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes row 3 is exist in `reference_df` but not in `df`. So need to have that in the expected output. The logic for `gr1f` is to have those rows in `df` after merge and everything should follow the pattern ie combination `gr1f` A,B   `DP` l10yrs, l1yrs that is the pattern.

Comment: That's not exactly the best explanation. But see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `indicator` option you can use. Also, you're not looking for right merge, you are looking for outer merge:

```
df1 = (df.merge(reference_df[['gr2p','gr3a','DP']]
                .assign(gr1f=['A','B']*(len(reference_df)//2)),
                on = ['gr1f','gr2p','gr3a','DP'], 
                how='outer', indicator=True)
        .sort_values(['gr2p','gr3a'])
        .assign(source=lambda x: x._merge.map({'both':'df', 'right_only':'ref', 'left_only':'df'}))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
   gr1f gr2p gr3a      DP  num_vals1  num_vals2      _merge source
0     A   CC   AL   l1yrs   1.138045   0.166637        both     df
1     A   CC   AL  l10yrs   1.221787   0.045137        both     df
2     B   CC   AL  l10yrs   1.700000   0.120000        both     df
3     B   CC   AL   l1yrs        NaN        NaN  right_only    ref
4     A   CC  DEL   l1yrs   1.159031   0.141340   left_only     df
5     B   CC  DEL   l1yrs   1.200000   0.870000   left_only     df
6     A   CC  DEL  l10yrs   1.500000   0.033442   left_only     df
7     B   CC  DEL  l10yrs   1.238342   0.012334   left_only     df
8     A   DD  DEL   l1yrs        NaN        NaN  right_only    ref
9     B   DD  DEL   l1yrs        NaN        NaN  right_only    ref
10    A   DD  DEL  l10yrs        NaN        NaN  right_only    ref
11    B   DD  DEL  l10yrs        NaN        NaN  right_only    ref
```

Comment: hey can you check your answer aligns with the expected output ;)

Comment: I was just about to ask, why row 3 is `reference_df`? That combination is not in `reference_df`

Comment: you may be right. maybe ı should not said reference df. Instead just another df to merge. thanks for your time on this though. it perfectly alignes with the problrm statement